# get value not id i datalist jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5.8, html-datalist

i´m filling a datalist from database with ajax:

```
$("#localBlogInput").on("keyup", function(e){
        console.log($("#localBlogInput").val());

        var form = $('#searchRestaurant');

        $.ajax({
            url: "blog/search/"+$("#localBlogInput").val(),
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: form.data('type'),
            success: function(data){
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                $("#localBlog").append(`
                    <option id="${response[0]["id"]}" value="${response[0]["id"]}">${response[0]["name"]}</option>
                `);


                console.log(restaurantId);
    
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){

                var response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

                /*if (response.errors.name) {
                    $(form).find('input[name="name"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $(form).find('.name-error').html(response.errors.name);
                } else if (response.errors.email) {
                    $(form).find('input[name="email"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $(form).find('.email-error').html(response.errors.email);
                } else if (response.errors.phone) {
                    $(form).find('input[name="phone"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $(form).find('.phone-error').html(response.errors.phone);
                } else if (response.errors.comments) {
                    $(form).find('input[name="comments"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $(form).find('.comments-error').html(response.errors.comments);
                } else if (response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse) {
                    $(form).find('input[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $(form).find('.g-recaptcha-response-error').html(response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse);
                }*/
            }
        });
    });
```

all it´s ok, but i need that option don´t show id options and in input i wnat to appear name of my `response` now is:

[image]

i need name:

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: So set the proper value on the options you are creating then?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your response, y need "Restaurante el portugués" into input text

Comment: Yeah, so? Set that as the option value then.

Comment: @CBroe how i can¿? i don´t know very well to do this

Comment: You are already outputting the name as the option text content, between the `<option>` and `</option>` tags. So, put the same thing into the `value` attribute - seriously, how hard can that be?

Comment: @CBroe ok, thanks for help. Too i have a doubt why do it´s duplicating my values? how i can avoid this?

Comment: Because you make your AJAX request on every keyup event, and keep on adding options all the time?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for all. i want to do a prediction from database data, when you are writing That appear a one data only that it´s same that you are writing

Answer (score 0):

You just need to capture the element and take out its value. When you get the response from the ajax request you just print out the name inside the `<option value="">`

```
$("#localBlogInput").on("keyup", function(e){
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("localBlogInput").value; // JAVASCRIPT
    var form = $('#searchRestaurant');

    $.ajax({
        url: "blog/search/" + inputVal,
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: form.data('type'),
        success: function(data){
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
            
            $("#localBlog").append(`
                <option id="${response[0]["id"]}" value="${response[0]["name"]}">${response[0]["name"]}</option>
            `);


            console.log(restaurantId);

        },
        error: function(jqXHR){

            var response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

            /*if (response.errors.name) {
                $(form).find('input[name="name"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.name-error').html(response.errors.name);
            } else if (response.errors.email) {
                $(form).find('input[name="email"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.email-error').html(response.errors.email);
            } else if (response.errors.phone) {
                $(form).find('input[name="phone"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.phone-error').html(response.errors.phone);
            } else if (response.errors.comments) {
                $(form).find('input[name="comments"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.comments-error').html(response.errors.comments);
            } else if (response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse) {
                $(form).find('input[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').addClass('is-invalid');
                $(form).find('.g-recaptcha-response-error').html(response.errors.gRecaptchaResponse);
            }*/
        }
    });
});
```